# tracemalloc: cannot capture higher frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, memory-leaks, malloc

I'm trying to find out memory leaks in a huge project using `tracemalloc` for extracting code frames. However, I cannot get more than one deepest frame, which is useless for large projects with lots dependencies and myriads of nested calls. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html), I tried to use:

1. `tracemalloc.start` limit argument
2. `PYTHONTRACEMALLOC` env variable
3. `-X tracemalloc` command line argument

And the `tracemalloc.get_traceback_limit()` shows correct number that I've set. However, I still get only one frame per Traceback object. It works the same on Python versions 3.8.5 and 3.9.7 on different machines. What's wrong here?? How can I fix this?

Here is minimal example:

```py
import os
import tracemalloc

def get_top_malloc(trace_number):
    snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    snapshot = snapshot.filter_traces((
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"),
        tracemalloc.Filter(False, "<unknown>"),
    ))
    top_stats = snapshot.statistics("lineno")
    msg = []
    if trace_number > 0:
        msg.append(f"Top malloc {trace_number} lines")
        for index, stat in enumerate(top_stats[:trace_number]):
            msg.append(f"#{index}: {stat.size // 1024} KB, {stat.count} times")
            print(stat.traceback._frames)  # Only single frame is here!
            print(dir(stat.traceback))
            msg.extend(line for line in stat.traceback.format(limit=16))
        other = top_stats[trace_number:]
        if other:
            size = sum(stat.size for stat in other)
            msg.append(f"{len(other)} other: {size // 1024} KB")
    total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
    msg.append(f"Total allocated size: {total // 1024 // 1024} MB")
    return "\n".join(msg)


storage = {}

def func2():
    def func3():
        value = '3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971'
        value = value * 4096
        storage['pi'] = value
    func3()

def func1():
    func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tracemalloc.start(4)
    print(f"\n-- Limit: {tracemalloc.get_traceback_limit()}")
    func1()
    print(f"\n-- {get_top_malloc(1)}")
    tracemalloc.stop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, it is trivial yet not apparent. The `statistics(...)` method of snapshot objects takes a `key_type` argument which is used to group the traces, either by file (`"filename"`), file+line (`"lineno"`), or by whole traceback (`"traceback"`). I used the default value `"lineno"` which filters out everything excluding the last frame per each traceback, so switching to the `"traceback"` option solved the problem and allowed me to get all the frames I needed `:)`

Comment: Thanks for posting and answering your own question. The docs for tracemalloc make it really easy to hit this and wonder why, so your answer helped me.